# can you identify this connector?

Tags: connector

noticed this inside a old-ish Kindle. It's a cup with a single pin. Wondering what type of connector this is called and maybe who supplies it.

[image: connector]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It's a [U.FL connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirose_U.FL).**

Also known as UMCC (Ultraminiature Coax Connectors). You can get them from lots of places, like [Digikey](http://www.digikey.com/catalog/EN/partgroup/umcc-ultra-miniature-coax-connectors-u-fl-series/2344).

[image]

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

It's a Hirose U.FL connector. Wiki:

[U.FL connectors are commonly used in applications where space is of critical concern, most often Mini PCI cards for laptop computers. U.FL connectors are commonly used inside laptops and embedded systems to connect the Wi-Fi antenna to a Mini PCI card. Another common use is connecting GPS antennas.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirose_U.FL)

Comment: Here's an example of a WiFi antenna that uses this connector. It's for a PlayStation 3. http://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/Wifi-Antenna-Board-with-Cable-for-Sony-Playstation-3-PS3-Brand-New-Free-Fast-Shipping-12768/106046_584798759.html